# Strange bug in MSHTML Assembly

Tags: vb.net, mshtml

```
 Dim u As UInteger = 0
 Try
 Do
 u += 1
 j = DirectCast(o.item(d), HTMLTableRow).cells
 Loop
 Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox("Access No." & u & " throws：" & ex.GetType.ToString & "：" & ex.Message)
 End Try
```

This is the piece of code I used as a test - a dead loop, infinitely accessing the variable O (assigned in code before) and assigning it to the variable J with some operation (O and J are both MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection type). Under the debug mode, I can run it normally until the counter u reaches its upper limit. However, under the release mode, after loop for 5000~6000 times (in each test the number is different) it will throw "NullReferenceException". Note that I've just accessed O, never changed it, why is the exception? Is this a bug of MSHTML the assembly? Moreover, if I make a minor change:

```
 Dim u As UInteger = 0, v As Object
 Try
 Do
 u += 1
 v = DirectCast(o.item(d), HTMLTableRow)
 Loop
 Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox("Access No." & u & "throws：" & ex.GetType.ToString & "：" & ex.Message)
 End Try
```

That is, to remove the ".cells", and then there will be no exceptions. What's going on here? (This cannot be used as a workaround because in my program the ".cells" must be accessed)
If I use TryCatch block to ignore the exception and just try again, it won't run normally any more - throwing the exception for each loop. There must be some qualitative changes.

Comment: If it works in debug mode, but fails in release mode, my guess would be that the compiler is optimizing your code in such a way that it breaks. I would use a decompiling took, such as dotPeek, to look at the generated optimization code.

Comment: @Icemanind Thank you, but I'd rather give up my project if I have to learn ASM just for debugging. Any tangible advice?

Comment: MSHTML cannot have a bug, it doesn't contain any code.  It is just an interop assembly to access the DOM of a web browser.  Anything and everything can happen in a web browser, you are accessing DOM elements that a web page's Javascript might be messing with as well.  Yes, best to give up.

Comment: @Hans Passant But why is it able to loop more than 5,000 times before the exception?

Comment: Timing is critical, your code runs completely out of sync with the scripting code in the web browser.  Simply switching between the Debug and Release configuration is enough to change the timing.  So does making seemingly arbitrary changes to the code, makes it extra mystifying.  At its core is a threading race bug, they are always hard to diagnose and fix.

Comment: @Hans Passant That's why I'm here for some similar experiences. Quite annoying

Comment: You are in the wrong place, one way to increase the annoyance level.  Have a chat with whomever maintains that web page, they can tell you everything you need to know.  If nobody picks up the phone then you are probably not expected to succeed at this.  That is common, data is not free.

Answer (score 0):

OK, MSHTML, you win. I have to use the dumbest workaround. Just try...catch the exception and try again. After numerous tests, I got the following possible exceptions that must be handled:
COMException, when you can simply try the statement throwing this again.
UnauthorizedAccessException, when you can simply try again like the last one.
NullReferenceException, when you CANNOT simply try again as you'll again catch the same exception. You'll have to initialize a new HTMLDocument and reload the URL, then do the remaining work.
Wanting anyone with a more elegant solution. I swear I'll never use the hideous Assembly if possible.